# How do I stop Google Chrome from requesting to import Firefox settings on startup?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, browser, import

Every time I start a fresh instance of Google Chrome on my PC, I receive the following message:

> Sadly, your Mozilla Firefox settings are not available while that browser is running. To import those settings to Google Chrome, save your work and close all Firefox windows. Then click Continue.

Restarting my computer partially fixed this, but now it is happening again. I have tried moving my `User Data` folder to another directory, and uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome, neither of which have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently (Windows 7/x64, FF v.17 or so), and here's what helped me:

- The problem was caused by a broken Firefox profile (so reinstalling Chrome would not help);
- The profile was broken due to some mutually incompatible plugins that made FF to crash on exit with the FF process staying in memory;
- Even when FF process is forcibly closed, the profile remained broken;
- When Chrome is set up to import settings from FF, it seems to update bookmarks at every start;

Your problem may or may not be the same, just check it in a step-by-step sequence:

1. Disable automatic import from FF to Chrome by removing check marks in [this screen](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95418?hl=en). If you no longer need them synchronized, you are done;
2. Check that FF process is stopped at the moment of import to Chrome, use Task Manager; then retry importing;
3. Disable all plugins (not uninstalling, just disabling; you will be able to restore them quickly); then attempt to close FF gracefully and retry importing;
4. Run FF in [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/927369) and let it exit gracefully;
5. Try to recover your FF profile:

   1. Backup your profile before recovery (you seem to be able to do that);
   2. [Reset FF settings](https://support.mozilla.org/uk/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems)
   3. Try to import again

In my case, I did not have to do a recover. I use [FEBE extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/) for backup purposes, so I just found a point at which the profile was not broken.

Comment: What if I don't want to import Firefox to Chrome (actually, I'm going to do it the other way around in a few days), just follow step one?

Comment: I honestly don't remember what I did to fix this, but it's been fixed for 2 years so have an accepted answer!